# Tags aren't replaced with strings in my opencart theme

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3, opencart-3

I have a problem: my translate language is not working. Tags aren't changed to strings.

How to solve that issue?

[image]

Comment: Here, I think, issue is in your language. please check and make sure. You have install proper language version installed according to your OpenCart version.

Comment: What is your version of OpenCart? Can you show few PHP code snippets what render the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

It seems *plausible* that your language pack has not been installed correctly.

To install a language package, you have to transfer **all your files** on your server (keeping the same structure) on the roots of a previously installed OpenCart.

After that, open your OpenCart backend and follow these steps:

1. Navigate to `System -> Localisation -> Languages`
2. Click the `Add New` button
3. Fill in the following values :

   1. *Language Name* : name of the language, for example `French`
   2. *Code* : code of your language, for example `fr`
   3. *Locale* : localization of your language, for example `fr,fr-FR,fr_FR.UTF-8,french`
   4. *Image* : flag image for the language, for example `fr.png`
   5. *Directory* : directory of your language pack, for example `fr-FR`
   6. *Status* : `Enabled`
   7. *Sort Order*: `1`
4. Save these changes
5. Navigate to `System -> Settings`
6. Click on the tab `Local` and define your standard languages for frontend and backend (backend language will not change **before** this step)
7. Save these changes
8. Installation is complete